# Increasing probability of middle-large values decreases skewness more than large values?

Tags: probability, distributions, skewness

I found this counterintuitive result and want to check with you folks if I did not make any mistakes.

Imagine a simple uniform distribution, of all values between 1 to 100. I would expect that increasing the frequency of 100s would decrease its skewness (*sensu* Fisher formula) from 0 to something negative. Also, I would expect that increasing the frequency of 99's would have a similar effect but less pronounced. After all, we are still increasing the asymmetry of this distribution, but with less intensity .

Yet, this is not what I found. Adding a second 100 to the distribution reduces skewness but reduces it less than adding a second 99. What is wrong in my logic? Shouldn't skewness be monotonically decreasing with increasing high values?

I even did a general, add-a-value-to-distribution function, to see the effect more clearly. Lo and behold, the relationship of skewness and the value added is highly nonlinear.

Doesn't that contradict the idea of skewness?

```
library(e1071)
incskew = function(x) {skewness(c(1:100,x),type=1)}
skews = sapply(1:100,incskew)
plot(skews)
```

[image: Skewness plot]

Comment: The intuitiveness of a moment decreases as the moment increases.

Mean --- Highly intuitive
Variance --- Sort of intuitive
Skewness --- Not too intuitive
Kurtosis ----  Yikes!

Comment: +1 ... Indeed I have seen quite a few basic textbooks and many websites which show any of several variations of a diagram that purports to display distributions that are more, equally, and less kurtotic than the normal, but what they actually show is three seemingly identically-shaped distributions with clearly different variances. Some *don't even manage to change the spread*,  just altering the height, and hence the area under the curve! It's most strange. There's also some that do manage to vary the kurtosis but obscure the intuition by also changing the variance at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Introducing an extra value changes the mean and the variance and third moment about the mean, and they interact to affect the skewness calculation.

Your chart could be continuous as the extra value does not need to be an integer: for example if it had been $50.5$ then you would still have a symmetric distribution and zero skewness, and the middle of your chart suggests that.

Or you could have introduced the new value outside the existing range of data.  If it had been $101$, you would still have a uniform set of data with a slightly higher mean and variance but with zero skewness.  Having $100$ as the extra value is close to that, which is why you only see small (negative) skewness in that case.

So it is reasonable to expect the largest magnitude of impact to be somewhere where the extra value is well above $50.5$ and well below $101$. And that is what you have observed.

Here is your graph made continuous and extended a little outwards, with vertical lines at $0$ and $50.5$ and $101$

[image: curve]

Comment: Hum, I wonder when does skewness has the expected behavior, if there is a way to manipulate values to decrease skewness monotonically. Perhaps, changing a non zero value for an 100?

Comment: Could you please tell us what the "expected behavior" might be a little more specifically?